# How to print the key of a dictionary but not it's value? [python]

Tags: python, dictionary

I know this is probably extremely simple and I'm forgetting something, but I cannot remember how to print the key of a dictionary. The specific problem is I have a dictionary of parts of an animal that can attack, and the value is the verb used to attack, e.g: {'teeth': 'bites'}

It looks like this:

```
attack_part = random.choice(list(self.attacking_parts))

print('The', self.name, self.attacking_parts[attack_part], 'you with their', self.attacking_parts.keys() + '!')
```

But when I use this what happens is:

```
The bear scratches you with their scrathes!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attack_part` variable in you code is the key of your `dict`. When you are doing the `self.attacking_parts[attack_part]`, you are fetching the value corresponding to `attack_part` key in you `self.attacking_parts` dict. Whereas doing `self.attacking_parts.keys()` returns the list of all the keys present in the dict.

Hence, instead you should be using your print statement like:

```
print('The', self.name, self.attacking_parts[attack_part], 'you with their', attack_part + '!')
```